# How to add conditions on shipping methods over price?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, shipping-methods

I need to trigger the free shipping option over $150 and charge a flat $5 handling fee with free shipping but if a specific product is added in cart this rule should not be applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do create new shipping method similar free shipping and do your customization in that method's **collectRates** method as per your requirement.
Check this blog https://techflarestudio.com/how-to-add-custom-free-shipping-based-on-cart-conditions-and-hide-other-methods-if-applicable/.

**Or** you can ovveride default shipping method and do your customization in that.